# Exporting a Pages doc without changing spacing

Tags: pdf, pages, font

I have many Pages documents containing song lyrics and guitar chords. Each chord is above a specific word of the song.

I need to export it to a web app. Everything I have tried changes the spacing and the chords appear above the wrong words. How can I do this?
I have tried:

- Copy and paste into the other app  ->  chords are above wrong words
- Export to pdf, -> copy and paste from pdf to app ->  no line ends (no returns)
- Export to rtf, -> copy and paste from rtf to app  ->  chords are above wrong words
- Export to plain text  ->  chords are above wrong words
- In Pages, changing to a monospace font -> chords move to be above wrong words

I cannot start with a monospace font and type in the songs, because they (about 100 of them) are already existing in Pages.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to share a document?

Comment: This may also depend on what the web app uses for formatting.  Knowing what the app is [easier if it needs no user account] may help.

Comment: Do you have Word?  You could try exporting to word and from that to html.

Comment: I  can't find a way to add a doc to a comment here. But I'll just describe an example.  In Pages, type "One  Two  Three  Four" and on the next line, type "1    2    3    4" so that each number is below the first letter of its word. The next step would be to copy and paste it onto the app. But you would need to sign up, create a song and navigate to the lyric entry section.  An easier way to test it is to just copy and paste it into a new .txt document in TextEdit.  It seems to have the same behaviour.  If it could be solved there it might also work for the web app. I don't have Word on my Mac.

Comment: The web app is BandHelper.     www.bandhelper.com    It has 2 parts - a web app for entering songs and an iPad/iPhone app for displaying the songs during a performance. The problem can be observed in the web app alone - there is no need to get the iPad app.